Why is $\exists y \ \forall x \ \forall z \ :y + z^2 \geq x$ false in $\mathbb{Z}$?
Let $P$ be the predicate $P(x, y, z) = y + z^2 \geq x, \quad x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}.$
The professor grading my exam said that this statement is false:
$\exists y \ \forall x \ \forall z \ :P(x, y, z)$
But I think that the statement is true, because you can choose $y=x$ and it will be true for all values of $x$ and $z,$ because $\forall z:z^2 \geq 0.$

But when you choose $y=x$ how do you handle a different choice of $x$?  There is one $y$ that should work for all $x$, but you have bound $x$ and $y$ together.

@Randall aha I see, y is the same independently of the value of x...

I've edited your title so that people browsing questions by title can actually see what your question is about. Please try to pick informative titles!

You cannot choose $y=x$. The expression first quantifies over $y$, which means in order for it to be true, you need to pick one $y$, and that one single value of $y$ must then ensure that no matter what $x$ and $z$ are, the expression $y+z^2 \geq x$ is true.

To caricature your reasoning, if I have $P(x,y) = y\text{ has the same surname as }x,$ then what you are saying is that $\exists y\forall x: P(x,y)$ is true on the set of humans, because we can just set $y=x$ and then of course the two have the same surname.
This is absurd of course, and it's clear immediately if you just consider the fact that the expression $\exists y \forall x: P(x,y)$ reads, in natural language, as "there exists some human $y$ such that if $x$ is any other human, then $y$ has the same surname as $x$", or in simplified terms,

There exists a human that has the same surname as all other humans.

